# What is a LINT/synthesis safe statement to throw an error at compile time?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have a module that is passed a `parameter` then instantiates another module corresponding to the defined parameter.

However, in the event that a case isn't defined for a certain combination of parameters, I would like an error to be thrown at compile time to highlight the problem, like so:

```
generate
if (PARAM1 == 1 && PARAM2 == 2) begin

   // instantiate module logic_A

end else if (PARAM1 == 2 && PARAM2 == 1) begin              

   // instantiate module logic_B

end else begin

   // throw an error at compile time if we haven't
   // defined a case for those parameters 

end
endgenerate
```

However, this code still needs to be synthesizable (in Verilog, not SystemVerilog) and pass LINTing, despite the inserted error.

Does anyone know what I could use in this situation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered very similar question on the sister site, Electronics StackExchange, for "[a way of conditionally triggering a compile-time error in verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/71226/17779)." The solution is to conditional an instantiate an modules that does not exist. I recommend the non-existing module have a very long name and meaningful name the explains the error. This also reduces the risk of the non-existing modules accidentally having the same name as an existing module.

```
generate
if (PARAM1 == 1 && PARAM2 == 2) begin : use_logicA
   // instantiate module logic_A
end
else if (PARAM1 == 2 && PARAM2 == 1) begin : use_logicB
   // instantiate module logic_B
end
else begin : illegal
   illegal_parameter_condition_triggered_will_instantiate_an non_existing_module();
end
endgenerate
```

This works because checking the existence of the non-existing-module isn't done until after the parameter values are evaluated during the elaboration stage.

---

The better solution would be to use the SystemVerilog approach; specifically with a simulator complement with the IEEE Std 1800-2009 standard or newer. Then you can use `$error()` and give a more meaningful message to go with the error (For example, print the parameter values that triggered the error condition). You can read more about it in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) 20.11 *Elaboration system tasks*

```
generate
if (PARAM1 == 1 && PARAM2 == 2) begin : use_logicA
   // instantiate module logic_A
end
else if (PARAM1 == 2 && PARAM2 == 1) begin : use_logicB
   // instantiate module logic_B
end
else begin : illegal
   $error("Expected PRAM1/2 to be 1/2 or 2/1, but was %0d/%0d", PARAM1, PARAM2 );
end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little clunky and I don't know what your lint tool is checking, but how about this:

```
generate
  if (PARAM1 == 1 && PARAM2 == 2) begin

    // instantiate module logic_A

  end else if (PARAM1 == 2 && PARAM2 == 1) begin              

    // instantiate module logic_B

  end else begin

    reg ILLEGAL_VALUES_ON_PARAM1_AND_PARAM2;
    reg DUMMYO, DUMMYI;
    always @(posedge ILLEGAL_VALUES_ON_PARAM1_AND_PARAM2 or negedge ILLEGAL_VALUES_ON_PARAM1_AND_PARAM2)
      DUMMYO <= DUMMYI;

  end
endgenerate
```

This gives the following error on Quartus when I set `PARAM1` to 3:

> Error (10239): Verilog HDL Always Construct error at synth_assertion.v(18): event control cannot test for both positive and negative edges of variable "ILLEGAL_VALUES_ON_PARAM1_AND_PARAM2"

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There is nothing in verilog for this. You cannot do it at compilation.

But you can do something to dump errors and exit at time '0' in simulation.

In system verilog you can add an assertion:

```
initial assert(0) else $fatal("--error--");
```

or just

```
initial $fatal("--error--");
```

otherwise something like that:

```
 initial begin $display("--error--"); $finish; end
```

Both will provide a message at the beginning of simulation.

Comment: In SystemVerilog, you can just do `$fatal("message") in the else clause of the `generate-if`.

Comment: Just checked, in vcs 2015 it is implemented but requires a special compilation switch "-assert svaext".  vcs produces nice compilation-time message in such a case. Otherwise it detects a syntax error. With  'initial' it compiles without issues and produces run-time violation message.